# How to split profits from paid app

Tags: android, google-play

I'm a programmer from Canada that will be creating a paid mobile app for a business in Guatemala. The profits from the app will be split into three and given to my two partners and I. From what I understand, Google will send the app profit into my bank account once a month. Is it possible for Google to split the profit evenly into three accounts? If not, how could I do this so my partners know that they got their fair share of the profits?

Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming, but how to set up payments in an app store.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I understand. But if I cannot ask here, where else can I go to get my answer? I did not find anything about this topic.

Comment: I list a variety of Android developer support sites at http://www.andglobe.com. Most will not have Stack Overflow's topic restrictions.